Using bitwise operations to simulate an N-length hash table: is space complexity O(1) or O(n)?
I am solving a problem that requires O(1) space complexity to check for duplicate numbers. I wanted to use a hash table, but due to the O(1) space constraint, I used bitwise operations. However, I noticed that the size of ans grows with length n. Is the space complexity of this algorithm O(n) or O(1)? The array's length is n, and since it is less than 32, it cannot exceed the maximum length.
nums[i]=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]
ans = 0
for i in nums:
    if (ans >> i) & 1 == 0:
        ans += 1 << i
    else:
        print("repeat")
        return i


Is there a limit for the values as well, or can they be arbitrarily large?

This integer used to simulate a hash table is within the range of long long

If you want an O(1)-space algorithm then you may use an in-place sorting algorithm and then search for contiguous duplicates.

This is far worse than either O(n) or O(1) (assuming the usual n=input size). Your algorithm takes space proportional to the highest value in the input. If the input is [8000000000000], your algorithm will try to compute 1 << 8000000000000, which will take about a terabyte of memory.
When you use unbounded integer sizes, you cannot treat the memory consumption of an integer as constant. It is not possible to cram an unlimited amount of data into a fixed amount of memory, regardless of whether you use a hash table, arbitrary-precision integers, or any other data structure.
